# undefined method `configure' for Savon:Module

Tags: ruby, rubygems, savon

I'm getting the above error in a gem with this code snippet

```
Savon.configure do |config|
  config.log = false
  config.log_level = :error
  HTTPI.log = false
end
```

This code used to pass in past runs on Travis, so I'm not sure why this changed when I altered the Readme.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Part of this confusion comes from my situation--inheriting a gem to maintain--along with this line in the gemspec:

```
gem.add_dependency 'savon'
```

There's no [version number specified](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-add_development_dependency), so the newest run switched over to using Savon 2, which ditched the `Savon.configure` global behavior.  If you're in the same boat as me, changing this line to the last pre-2.0 version of Savon will resolve the issue:

```
gem.add_dependency 'savon', '~>1.2.0'
```

Then `bundle install` and you should be good.

---

Or you want to upgrade your code.  I know I do.

`Savon.configure` was removed from Savon 2.0 because the "[problem was global state](http://savonrb.com/version2.html#globals)".  The quickest way to keep the behavior the same in your app would be to define a app-level global hash in the same place.  You'd then pass this hash into every `Savon.client` call you make.  For instance:

```
# Where Savon.configure was called
APP_OPTS = {
  # disable request logging, silences HTTPI as well
  log:       false,
  # Don't log Laundry xmls to STDOUT
  log_level: :error,
  #... etc
}

# Elsewhere
@client = Savon::Client.new(APP_OPTS)
```

I'd consider this a starting point to migrating to the 2.0 configuration style.  Ideally, you should always consider the [client-specific 2.0 options available](http://savonrb.com/version2.html) when initializing each Savon client.

Comment: please everyone always pin your gem dependencies down to at least a major version. thanks for writing up this really helpful answer.

Comment: I wanted to ask, where you write that APP_OPTS, in a file in config/initializers like where the config code was? I was using savon 1.0 and was getting method not found with savon.config, but I have another project using it exactly the same way and works, is it possible that one of the dependencies throws that exception? thanks for your help

Comment: In my example, APP_OPTS is just an application constant.  The important line is `@client = Savon::Client.new(APP_OPTS)`, which should be initialized when you need an instance of the Savon (2.0) Client object.  As for your error, I'd double check your Gemfile.lock.  What you describe sounds exactly like a Savon 1 -> 2 error that I ran into

Comment: @EricHu the link you provided is 404: client-specific 2.0 options available